# How can i change the column values of csv file using with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here in my program I have 4 columns of csv file, in that x,y values having 0,0 values I want to change those 0,0 values to my desired values without changing other x,y values. Can you please help me how to change these values?

I tried this given code but other values of x,y values are also changing because here I am  adding 3 value for whole x, but I don't want change remaining values I want to change the 0,0 x,y values to my desired values only, so can you please guide me. Thank you in advance

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Tunnel.csv",delimiter= ',')
df['X'] = df['X'] + 3
df['Y'] = df['Y'] + 4

print(df)
```

This is my csv_file[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the df.loc method as follows:

```
df.loc[(df['X'] == 0) & (df['Y'] ==0) , ['X', 'Y'] ] =  3,4
```

Comment: here i want to change for 0,0 x,y values for depth and color i changed your code to like this but its didn't work.So please tell me where i did mistake df.loc[(df['X'] == 0) & (df['Y'] ==0) , ['X', 'Y', 'DEPTH','COLOR'] ] =  3,4,2.3,300

Comment: No it didn't give any error but values are remain same

Comment: @GouthamySri, when you do df.loc[(df['X'] == 0) & (df['Y'] ==0) , ['X', 'Y', 'DEPTH','COLOR'] ] = 3,4,2.3,300, you are defaulting the values of Depth and Colour to 2.3 and 300 for all rows where X=0 and y=0. Which is not correct.

Comment: Ok,how can i change the color and depth values for 0,0(x,y) values

Comment: Your code worked fine for me as it is the same logic as for the X and Y values. This also worked for me: df.loc[(df['X'] == 0) & (df['Y'] ==0) , ['DEPTH', 'COLOR'] ] =  2.3, 300

Answer (score 1):

You can select subframes of zero entries:

```
df[df['X'] == 0] += 3
df[df['Y'] == 0] += 4
```

To write your dataframe to a csv file named `file_name` use `to_csv`

```
file_name = 'file.csv'   
df.to_csv(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

another way around using with `df.iteritems`  :

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0, 2], 'b': [ 0, 2, 1]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  2
2  2  1
>>> for key, val in df.iteritems():
...     val[val == 0] = 3
...
>>> df
   a  b
0  3  3
1  3  2
2  2  1
```

Comment: This will be a lot slower and less efficient than the vectorized approaches proposed. You should avoid iterating unless necessary.

Comment: @roganjosh, thats what i said another way around.

Comment: use  `df.to_csv(file_name)`

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply function to set these values. Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('t.csv',header=None, names=['x','y','depth','color'])

dfc=df.copy()

dfc['x']=dfc['x'].apply(lambda t: 1 if t==0 else t)
dfc['y']=dfc['y'].apply(lambda t: 1 if t==0 else t)
```

Input:
[image: Input Data]

Output:
[image: Output Data]

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Rohan Hodarkar